# Apache PDFBox - Difference among PDFont types

Tags: java, pdfbox

I started recently to use PDFBox to process some PDF files. I loaded successfully the Roboto font, however, I don't understand the difference between PDType0Font, PDType1Font and PDTrueTypeFont. Which one is better to use?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the standard 14 fonts (times, helvetica, courier, symbol, zapf dingbats) => use `PDType1Font.HELVETICA` etc. (Only WinAnsiEncoding supported)

If you have type1 fonts on your computer and want to use these => use the PDType1Font constructor.

If you want to use TrueType fonts in an inefficient way (only 256 glyphs, no subsetting) => use `PDTrueTypeFont.load()`.

If you want to use TrueType fonts in an efficient way (more than 256 glyphs, subsetting) => use `PDType0Font.load()`. You can and should use the same font object for the whole PDF, i.e. don't create a new PDFont object for each page.

If you want to use TrueType collections, do this:

```
TrueTypeCollection ttc = new TrueTypeCollection(new File("C:/windows/fonts/mingliu.ttc"));
PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(doc, ttc.getFontByName("MingLiU"));
...
ttc.close(); // only after PDF has been saved
```

Comment: *"You can and should use the same font object for the whole PDF, i.e. don't create a new PDFont object for each page."* - ... unless you plan your PDF to later be split up and the individual pages contain considerably different subsets of the font. In this *special case* using separate `PDFont` objects for this font can be of advantage.

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr! I used `PDType0Font.load()` to load Roboto font

Comment: If the answer helped, please click on the checkmark.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr , up-voted. Its great info that you and @mkl are providing for `PDFBox` on SO. Is there any source / reference document of all such useful information? If not are you planning to write one?

Comment: @ScrapCode No, too busy with other stuff. Besides, few people read documentations anyway. We've had questions here on SO about things mentioned in the javadoc 